# How to refresh or reload pivot grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a simple task - I just need to refresh/reload pivot grid programmatically. When a user clicks on a button, I need to pass some variables and realod the store. This is what I tried:

```
//1. Standard load method. Does not work - it does not make a request to the server
olap_grid.store.load();
//2. Try to "refresh". Results in an error: olap_grid.refresh is not a function
olap_grid.refresh();
```

So, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I also tried this:

```
//3.
olap_grid.view.store.load();
//4.
olap_grid.view.refresh();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Well, you'd better say something before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If grid has a store, you can reach it;

`olap_grid.getStore();`

If you want to reload store with some params you can use;

```
olap_grid.getStore().load({
    params: { paramkey: 'paramvalue' }
});
```